# How to further fine-tune a transformer NLP model on domain specific dataset, after general fine-tuning

Tags: transformer, finetuning

I would like to fine-tune a pre-trained BERT-like model for a semantic similarity analysis task in the fashion of the SNLI/MNLI task (i.e. classify sentence pairs to "entailment" or "contradiction"). I have my own domain specific dataset but it is very small. For that reason I planned to fine-tune the model first on a large "general" dataset like the MNLI and then further fine-tune it on my own data. This way I want to take advantage of the large publicly available dataset and thus, hopefully improve results on my small dataset.

My questions here are:

1. Does this approach make sense in general for language models? Or would phenomena like catastrophic forgetting break my plan anyway?
2. How do I design the training steps? Should I freeze some of the (additional) fine-tuned layers (apart from the embedding layers of course) or do I simply resume training from last checkpoint?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to hyperparameter tuning, automatic tuners such as [keras tuner](https://keras.io/keras_tuner/) is the way to go. Specially consider using Bayesian optimization, since it can relatively outperform the other methods such as Grid and Radnom search.
PS: Be sure to set the initial random points of the Bayesian Optimizer very high (at least 30, even higher if you have a really big hyperspace) to ensure that Bayesian Optimizer has enough prior data to build the surrogate model.